# Comparing two arrays by first letters of each element and printing if equal

Tags: bash, awk

Let's say I have two arrays (A and B)

in directory A

```
#!/bin/bash
A=( $(ls *txt) )
```

directory A contains:

```
fox_abdce.txt
rabbit_abdce.txt
lemom_asnrndna.txt
```

in directory B

```
#!/bin/bash
B=( $(ls *txt) )
```

directory B contains:

```
fox_zzzzzz.txt
rabbit_zzzedd.txt
lemom_kokoijijim.txt
```

Or, input with type set (this could be generalized to anything similar)

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a A=([0]="fox_abcde.txt" [1]="lemom_asnrndna.txt" [2]="rabbit_abcde.txt") 
declare -a B=([0]="fox_zzzzzz.txt" [1]="lemom_kokoijijim.txt" [2]="rabbit_zzzedd.txt")
```

I want to compare them to find out if all of them are similar by the first 3 letters

I would use AWK like this to find out if two columns from a csv file have the same initial three letters:

```
#!/bin/bash
export NUMBER_OF_DIGITS=3
```

matching

```
awk -F, '{if(substr($1, 1, $NUMBER_OF_DIGITS) == substr($2, 1, $NUMBER_OF_DIGITS)) print}' file.csv
```

Not matching

```
awk -F, '{if(substr($1, 1, $NUMBER_OF_DIGITS) != substr($2, 1, $NUMBER_OF_DIGITS)) print}' file.csv
```

How could I apply the same interrogation but using the arrays directly?

In this case the output should be anything with everything that matches

```
fox_abdce.txt
rabbit_abdce.txt
lemom_asnrndna.txt

fox_zzzzzz.txt
rabbit_zzzedd.txt
lemom_kokoijijim.txt
```

OR

```
fox_abdce.txt             fox_zzzzzz.txt
rabbit_abdce.txt          rabbit_zzzedd.txt
lemom_asnrndna.txt        lemom_kokoijijim.txt
```

Comment: `A=( $(ls *txt) )` is not a reliable way to populate an array with the list of files in a directory.  See [Bash Pitfalls #1 (for f in $(ls *.mp3))](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29).

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) identifies several problems with the code.  The report that it produces includes links to more information about the problems and how to fix them.  It's a good idea to run [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) on all new and modified shell code.

Comment: Most errors with this code were comments and the lack of #!/bin/bash
But the code is working in #!/bin/bash

Comment: Why are you wanting to use shell arrays rather than just processing the directory contents directly with awk?

Comment: because arrays are more generalizable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumptions:

- file names do not include embedded linefeeds
- both arrays have the same number of entries
- we're to compare array entries that have the same array index

Adding a 'not matching' data point:

```
A=("fox_abdce.txt" "rabbit_abdce.txt" "ignore_me" "lemom_asnrndna.txt")
B=("fox_zzzzzz.txt" "rabbit_zzzedd.txt" "not_me" "lemom_kokoijijim.txt")
```

Fixing the `NUMBER_OF_DIGITS` issue:

```
#### replace this:

NUMBER_OF_DIGITS=(3)

#### with this:

NUMBER_OF_DIGITS=3

#### then feed to awk via a -v flag/arg, eg:

awk -v awk_var_name="OS_var_value"
```

One `awk` idea using process substitution:

```
echo "########## matching"

awk -v len="${NUMBER_OF_DIGITS}" '
FNR==NR                                  { a[FNR]=$0; next }
substr(a[FNR],1,len) == substr($0,1,len) { print a[FNR],$0 }
' <(printf "%s\n" "${A[@]}") <(printf "%s\n" "${B[@]}")

echo "########## not matching"

awk -v len="${NUMBER_OF_DIGITS}" '
FNR==NR                                  { a[FNR]=$0; next }
substr(a[FNR],1,len) != substr($0,1,len) { print a[FNR],$0 }
' <(printf "%s\n" "${A[@]}") <(printf "%s\n" "${B[@]}")
```

This generates:

```
########## matching
fox_abdce.txt fox_zzzzzz.txt
rabbit_abdce.txt rabbit_zzzedd.txt
lemom_asnrndna.txt lemom_kokoijijim.txt

########## not matching
ignore_me not_me
```

---

Assumptions:

- file names do not include embedded commas (otherwise we will need to choose a different delimiter for the `paste` command)

A different approach using `paste` to join the two sets of process substitution:

```
$ paste -d, <(printf "%s\n" "${A[@]}") <(printf "%s\n" "${B[@]}")
fox_abdce.txt,fox_zzzzzz.txt
rabbit_abdce.txt,rabbit_zzzedd.txt
ignore_me,not_me
lemom_asnrndna.txt,lemom_kokoijijim.txt
```

Feeding the `paste` output to `awk`:

```
echo "########## matching"

awk -F, -v len="${NUMBER_OF_DIGITS}" '
substr($1,1,len) == substr($2,1,len)
' <(paste -d, <(printf "%s\n" "${A[@]}") <(printf "%s\n" "${B[@]}"))

echo "########## not matching"

awk -F, -v len="${NUMBER_OF_DIGITS}" '
substr($1,1,len) != substr($2,1,len)
' <(paste -d, <(printf "%s\n" "${A[@]}") <(printf "%s\n" "${B[@]}"))
```

This generates:

```
########## matching
fox_abdce.txt,fox_zzzzzz.txt
rabbit_abdce.txt,rabbit_zzzedd.txt
lemom_asnrndna.txt,lemom_kokoijijim.txt

########## not matching
ignore_me,not_me
```

Comment: Not sure if it is the version, but my awk, when using awk -v awk_var_name="OS_var_value", spits: Usage: awk [POSIX or GNU style options] -f progfile [--] file ... and does nothing

Comment: what is the output from `awk --version`?  did you cut-n-paste the code directly from the answer into your env, or did you manually type it into your env? (trying to rule out an issue of a typo on your end)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the three-letter prefixes are unique in both arrays, the simplest way is to “pre-index” one of them using an associative array and do lookups that way.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -euo pipefail

make_simple_index() {
  local -n _input="$1"   # declare -a
  local -n _output="$2"  # declare -A
  local s
  _output=()
  for s in "${_input[@]}"; do
    _output["${s::3}"]="$s"
  done
}

declare -ar a=('fox_abcde.txt'
               'lemom_asnrndna.txt'
               'rabbit_abcde.txt') 
declare -ar b=('fox_zzzzzz.txt'
               'lemom_kokoijijim.txt'
               'rabbit_zzzedd.txt')

declare -A index_of_b
make_simple_index b index_of_b

# Just for debugging / illustration:
printf '%s %s %s\n\n' "${index_of_b[@]@A}" 1>&2

for s in "${a[@]}"; do
  [[ "${index_of_b["${s::3}"]}" ]] &&
  printf '%s %s\n' "$s" "${index_of_b["${s::3}"]}" || :
done
```

Possible output:

```
declare -A index_of_b=([rab]="rabbit_zzzedd.txt" [fox]="fox_zzzzzz.txt" [lem]="lemom_kokoijijim.txt" )

fox_abcde.txt fox_zzzzzz.txt
lemom_asnrndna.txt lemom_kokoijijim.txt
rabbit_abcde.txt rabbit_zzzedd.txt
```

With duplicate 3-letter prefixes the approach would be just slightly more complicated; one would e.g. map the prefixes to “lists” of indices of matching elements in the original arrays, pre-index both arrays that way, then iterate over one of the index arrays and output a Cartesian product of matching prefixes.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -euo pipefail

make_complex_index() {
  local -n _input="$1"   # declare -a
  local -n _output="$2"  # declare -A
  local -i i
  _output=()
  for i in "${!_input[@]}"; do
    _output["${_input[i]::3}"]+=" $((i))"
  done
}

declare -ar a=('fox'{1,2}'_abcde.txt'
               'lemom_asnrndna.txt'
               'rabbit_abcde.txt')
declare -ar b=('fox'{3,4}'_zzzzzz.txt'
               'lemo'{n,m}'_kokoijijim.txt'
               'rabbit_zzzedd.txt')

declare -A index_of_{a,b}
make_complex_index a index_of_a
make_complex_index b index_of_b

# Just for debugging / illustration:
printf '%s %s %s\n' "${index_of_a[@]@A}" 1>&2
printf '%s %s %s\n\n' "${index_of_b[@]@A}" 1>&2

declare -ai indices_{a,b}
declare -i i{a,b}
for prefix in "${!index_of_a[@]}"; do
  indices_b=(${index_of_b["$prefix"]:-})
  if ((${#indices_b[@]})); then
    indices_a=(${index_of_a["$prefix"]})
    for ia in "${indices_a[@]}"; do
      for ib in "${indices_b[@]}"; do
        printf '%s %s\n' "${a[ia]}" "${b[ib]}"
      done
    done
  fi
done
```

Possible output:

```
declare -A index_of_a=([rab]=" 3" [fox]=" 0 1" [lem]=" 2" )
declare -A index_of_b=([rab]=" 4" [fox]=" 0 1" [lem]=" 2 3" )

rabbit_abcde.txt rabbit_zzzedd.txt
fox1_abcde.txt fox3_zzzzzz.txt
fox1_abcde.txt fox4_zzzzzz.txt
fox2_abcde.txt fox3_zzzzzz.txt
fox2_abcde.txt fox4_zzzzzz.txt
lemom_asnrndna.txt lemon_kokoijijim.txt
lemom_asnrndna.txt lemom_kokoijijim.txt
```

Comment: See [Bash Pitfalls #60 (set -euo pipefail)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#set_-euo_pipefail).

Comment: At least one of the 10+ lists of “pitfalls” comes up each time I mention `set -e`. My response is that there are *way* more pitfalls in **not** using it. Airbags and seatbelts have pitfalls too, but are still better used (both) than unused. My experience tells me to use and recommend `set -e` and require it in code reviews, because scripts without `set -e` tend to be riddled with hard-to-spot glitches. Sure, using functions as “conditions” in `if` / `&&` / `||` is tricky. Don’t use them that way and `set -e` will “propagate” failures as expected. Still less room for error than without `set-e`.

Comment: One “pitfall” not on the list(s) (which I personally consider the most serious) affects assignments at declaration time: `x=$(false)` fails whereas `local x=$(false)` “succeeds”. Under `set -e` this requires _ugly_ constructs like `local x; x="$(can_fail)"; local -r x;` to keep the “`set -e` effect” working. In my opinion, Bash needs an option called (e.g.) `substitutionfail`, a command substitution counterpart of `pipefail`. Still, I’m happy to use seatbelts, because flying through the windscreen is worse than a seatbelt cut. `set -e` is like a seatbelt. Imperfect, but great to have.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ NUMBER_OF_DIGITS=3
$ awk -v nd=$NUMBER_OF_DIGITS '
    NR==FNR{
        prefix[NR] = substr($1,1,nd)
        files[NR] = $0
        next
    }
    prefix[FNR] == substr($1,1,nd){
        print files[FNR] "    \t    " $0
    }
' <(find ./A -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "%P\n") \
  <(find ./B -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "%P\n")
fox_abdce.txt               fox_zzzzzz.txt
lemom_asnrndna.txt          lemom_kokoijijim.txt
rabbit_abdce.txt            rabbit_zzzedd.txt
```